# app.asar --nod ? What programme is it (in my netstat statistics?

Tags: networking, netstat

What is `app.asar --nod`?

```
jerzy@jerzy:~$ sudo netstat -tupln
[sudo] password for jerzy: 

Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50005   O.0.0.0:*   LISTEN    1798/app.asar --nod
```

Comment: I'm guessing `-nod` is a truncated string that should be `--node` and then possibly something else.  You can get more information using `ps` on the reported PID: `ps -p 1798`.  Also, does the output actually say `O.0.0.0:*` (with an `O`, "ooh")?

Comment: ps -p 1798 returned :                                                                                       
 1798 ?        00:00:31 scatter                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                       
As you can see the name of the programme (scatter) is totally unrelated to app.asar  --nod (in the statistics from my netstat)  Why so?

Comment: Yes, the output does say 0.0.0.0:*    The programme in question is scatter ( https://get-scatter.com/download )

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this:
https://github.com/electron/asar

used by electron apps.
I notice it when I run Signal.

Answer (score 1):

To find out more about it, use

`ps -p <PID>`

where PID is the process id in front of the process name in the netstat output.

For me it was Discord.

Answer (score 0):

If you google for scatter and app.asar, you'll find references to ScatterDesktop, which seems to be a digital signature provider for crypto currencies.

So if you're using an Ethereum wallet or similar stuff, the process probably belongs to that. Otherwise, someone else has installed it on your computer and you should treat the machine as compromised and unsuitable to use with any critical data.